# where to write the final (else statement) in this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am new at learning python and i like to try things so I wrote these `if` and `else` statements in (python 3.4.3) shell but I don't know where to write the final else statement that leads to all 4 values are false.

note that :

```
a=False
b=False
c=False
d=False
```

This is a screenshot of the code because the code inserting feature here always cutting a big part of my code
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Pro tip: Never type in that large amount of code directly into the Python shell. Store the code in a file and run Python on that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some logical errors in it. For example, it will reach "b is false, the rest are true" anytime `a` is `False` and `b` is true, even if `c` and/or `d` are `False`. To do this right, you need to test all the variables all the way down to `d`, no matter what you found for `a`, `b` and `c`. If you do that, you will end up with 16 'leaves' at the `d` level, and you will write all the `print` statements in these leaves. Below is a version of your code with the extra branches added. The "all false" section ends up at the else/else/else/else branch, where it should be.

```
if a:
    if b:
        if c:
            if d:
                print("a,b,c,d are true")
            else:
                print("d is false; a,b,c are true")
        else:  # c false
            # more detail added below
            if d:
                print("c is false; a,b,d are true")
            else:
                print("c,d are false; a,b are true")
    else:  # b false
        # more detail added below
        if c:
            if d:
                print("b is false; a,c,d are true")
            else:
                print("b,d are false; a,c are true")
        else:  # c false
            if d:
                print("b,c are false; a,d are true")
            else:
                print("b,c,d are false; a is true")
else:  # a false
    if b:
        if c:
            if d:
                print("a is false; b,c,d are true")
            else:
                print("a,d are false; b,c are true")
        else:  # c false
            # more detail added below
            if d:
                print("a,c are false; b,d are true")
            else:
                print("a,c,d are false; b is true")
    else:  # b false
        # more detail added below
        if c:
            if d:
                print("a,b are false; c,d are true")
            else:
                print("a,b,d are false; c is true")
        else:  # c false
            if d:
                print("a,b,c are false; d is true")
            else:
                print("a,b,c,d are false")
```

About your error -- you had code like the following, which is invalid:

```
if a:
    # something
else:
    # something else
else:
    print("a,b,c,d are false")
```

Comment: that was really very useful.  in your code you checked every single possibility for these values, i am gonna try to write it by myself now, thanks pro.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this much more simply without the **massive** `if-else` block of `code`.

If you have `4` `boolean` `variables`: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` then you can do the following:

```
print("a is", a, "b is", b, "c is", c, "and d is", d)
```

which will `print` something of the order:

```
a is False b is False c is False and d is False
```

---

Here are some `examples` to demonstrate some of the cases:

```
>>> a, b, c, d = True, True, True, True
>>> print("a is", a, "b is", b, "c is", c, "and d is", d)
a is True b is True c is True and d is True
>>> a, b, c, d = True, False, True, False
>>> print("a is", a, "b is", b, "c is", c, "and d is", d)
a is True b is False c is True and d is False
>>> a, b, c, d = False, False, True, True
>>> print("a is", a, "b is", b, "c is", c, "and d is", d)
a is False b is False c is True and d is True
```

---

Ah, I see now. You want to know why the `shell` is giving you an `error`. Well that is simply because you are trying to do `2` ``` else``statements ``` from one `if`.

The format for an `if` `statement` is:

```
if <condition>:
   code...
elif <condition>:
   code...
else:
   code...
```

where `elif` and `else` are *optional*.

The `syntax` that you used in that screenshot was:

```
if a:
   code...
else:
   code...
else:
ERROR
```

You just can't have `2` `else` clauses from one `if` `statement`! Maybe you meant to `indent` this further to match a different `statement`, but hopefully you understand why Python threw an `error` here.

Comment: thanks for answer but i don't just want to write a is False b is False c is False and d is False        i want a code that would check every single possibility of these values and give out the right output,   thanks again

Comment: @peter I think you are missing the point, this **will** do that as the commas in the `print` separate the `variables` from the `string` so this means their values will change. I will add some more examples to demonstrate

Comment: i understand you bro, but these values are just an example , i want to know why when i try to put the final else statement i got an error? , thanks again for caring mate

Comment: @peter I have added an explanation at the bottom of my code. Please feel free to up-vote and accept if it helps **:)**

Comment: you are a life savior bro   , i can't thank you enough.